# cannot convert component HeroComponent with id "hero" to HTML

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I am testing this tutorial:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveComponent.html#module-live-component-blocks

I want to make a dropdown menu using tailwind and live view.
For now I am just trying to do the tutorial...

these are my files

live/test.ex

```
defmodule HeroComponent do
  # If you generated an app with mix phx.new --live,
  # the line below would be: use MyAppWeb, :live_component
  use Phoenix.LiveComponent

  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div class="hero"><%= @content %></div>
    """
  end
end
```

reference in index.heex:

```
     <nav class="hidden md:flex space-x-10">
          <div class="relative">
            <!-- Item active: "text-gray-900", Item inactive: "text-gray-500" -->
            <button type="button" class="text-gray-500 group bg-white rounded-md inline-flex items-center text-base font-medium hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
              <span>Solutions</span>
              <!--
                Heroicon name: solid/chevron-down

                Item active: "text-gray-600", Item inactive: "text-gray-400"
              -->
              <svg class="text-gray-400 ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>

            <!--
              'Solutions' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.

              Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
                From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
                To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
                From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
                To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            -->

            <.live_component module={HeroComponent} id="hero"  />
             <div class="absolute z-10 -ml-4 mt-3 transform w-screen max-w-md lg:max-w-2xl lg:ml-0 lg:left-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2">
   
              <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
                <div class="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8 lg:grid-cols-2">
                  <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-600 to-indigo-600 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                      <!-- Heroicon name: outline/inbox -->
                      <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M20 13V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v7m16 0v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5m16 0h-2.586a1 1 0 00-.707.293l-2.414 2.414a1 1 0 01-.707.293h-3.172a1 1 0 01-.707-.293l-2.414-2.414A1 1 0 006.586 13H4" />
                      </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-4">
                      <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">Inbox</p>
                      <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">Get a better understanding of where your traffic is coming from.</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
```

the error --> cannot convert component HeroComponent with id "hero" to HTML.[image]

Comment: Can you share more of `index.heex`? Specifically what `.live_component` is nested in

Comment: Can you verify the html where you are mouting the live_component is in fact a live view module?